# REST: Creating an item with cross-referencing properties

Tags: rest

I'm currently designing a schema for a resource that is used in my app (simplified to an *'order'* here). I've got a bit tangled with cross-referencing / being able to reference a resource that doesn't yet have a concrete identifier.

I've got 3 possible designs below. Some are closer to the domain + mental model of the object (A + C), and B may be simpler, but involves a re-orientated mapping (for sending to the server) to solve the problem.

**My question:** Of the 3 designs below, which seems the most robust/correct? (Or, offer an improved solution)

---

**Detail:**

The resource I'm wanting to send in one request is:

> - Order
>
>   - Products[]
>   - Fees[]
>   - Customers[]

And some context / my constraints are:

- Each product & fee is assigned to a customer
- The 'customer' property is just a snapshot of text - and must be attached to one order. (It's not intended to be a set of reusable customers)
- In the domain, most of the UI/analysis centers around the totals of the order as a whole.

  - Only in a few cases do we look at the data from the 'per customer' view
- The same object is sometimes used for transient queries

  - *E.g.:* Calculate shipping. (So DB persistence is not always a given, for this resource schema)

**Option A: Create the customers first, then use their IDs**

If the customers are the dependency, then I could create them beforehand. Through input checking, I can keep each 'customer' associated to only 1 order.

This option accepts that it can't all be done in the one request.

**Note:** It also assumes that the customers must persist to DB. I can't, for example, run this same object through a transient 'calculate shipping' query.

```
POST: {
    name: "Person 1",
}
-> ID: 81

POST: {
    name: "Person 2",
}
-> ID: 92

{
    products: [{
        productId: 3,
        quantity: 2,
        customer: 81
    }, {
        productId: 4,
        quantity: 1,
        customer: 92
    }],
    fees: [{
        feeId: 21,
        amount: 30,
        customer: 81
    }, {
        feeID: 32,
        amount: 2,
        customer: 92
    }]
}
```

**Option B: Re-orientate the packet around the customer**

It seems clean - Though it would involve the UI mapping to this format, and the DB will likely map back to use the format similar to *Option A/C*.

```
{
    customerOrders: [{
        name: "Person 1",
        products: [{
            productId: 3,
            quantity: 2
        }],
        fees: [{
            feeId: 21,
            amount: 30
        }]
    }, {
        name: "Person 2",
        products: [{
            productId: 4,
            quantity: 1
        }],
        fees: [{
            feeID: 32,
            amount: 2
        }]
    }]
}
```

**Option C: Cross referencing properties, and temporary IDs**

This is similar to Option A, and just exploring if it can all be done in one request. Generating temp IDs + making the server deal with it seems awkward - but I assume there may actually be an elegant way to achieve it.

```
{
    products: [{
        productId: 3,
        quantity: 2,
        customer: "a"
    }, {
        productId: 4,
        quantity: 1,
        customer: "b"
    }],
    fees: [{
        feeId: 21,
        amount: 30,
        customer: "a"
    }, {
        feeID: 32,
        amount: 2,
        customer: "b"
    }],
    customers: [{
        name: "Person 1",
        tempId: "a"
    }, {
        name: "Person 2",
        tempId: "b"
    }]    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

because you want to use single call, all the references customer-product-fee are relative. Something like ID/IDREF in XML (see http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/xml/schema/ch09_03.htm). All you need to do is check the references are valid.

In my opinion option A is out of question (you wanted single request, right?); B and C differs only in the semantic: a person belongs to product/fee or product/fee belongs to a person. B seems to be the easiest to implement.

Answer (score 1):

The first concern is to understand the functional scope of your resource(s).  Using a order to create customers, for instance, may not be cohesive.  An /order resource should operate on order(s).

The second concern is to understand the nature of the resource you are POST/PUT/GET/DELETE-ing.  Is it an instance; is it a collection?  When using POST/PUT a convention to consider is to think of the resource as an instance ("order" in this case).

The third concern is to determine whether any of the contained objects are also resources.  "Products" certainly appears to be a candidate.

Finally, think of resources as having IDs that are URLs; and hence can be referenced as hypermedia in other resources.  Using an approach like [HAL](http://stateless.co/hal_specification.html) is a mechanism to reference external resources.

So your 1-call constraint might be a challenge here.  In fact 1 single call may effect reusability.  So option 1 is closest to answer.

For example, the order resource may contain a collections product customisations (1 general product customised by a specific customer).  The links provide reference to the product, the customer and self.

```
{
  "product_customisations" : [{
    "id" : "001",
    "qty" : 2,
    "fees" : {
      "type" : "fee_1",
      "amount" : {
        "amt" : "10.00",
        "currency" : "NZD"
      }
    }
    "_links" : {
      "self" : {"href" : "/products_customisations/001"},
      "product" : {""href" : "/products/001"},
      "customer" : {"href" : "/products/001"}
    }
  }]
}
```